# IMPORTHTML stuck on loading

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importhtml

Here's my problem, I've got an html page from my own web site which contains a lot of tables. I'm using IMPORTHTML in Google Sheets to import some of them in different spreadsheets. There's 4 different tables used in each of the spreadsheets, I've been doing this for something like the first 100 tables with no problem whatsoever.

This morning, I started a new spreadsheet, importing 4 other tables from the same html page and every importhtml is stuck at loading. I tried closing the browser with no succes.

I tried doing importdata to see if my website server might blocking me for some reason and it doesn't seem to be the case since I can import the HTML page with importdata.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Perhaps it has something to do with this console error that is now showing up: `This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.`

`IMPORTDATA()` is still working fine for me.

Comment: Same thing happening to most of my sheets. But, surprisingly in a few of them where i have scripts and thereby Authorizations already granted, importhtml is working. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a [known bug](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153637852) with `ImportHTML` and `ImportXML`, and the fix is expected to come in the next few days. Custom functions are [also broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/222342097?pli=1) and that breakage appears to be related to this issue.